# get all contact phone numbers with ContactsUI in swift

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I used ContactsUI to fetching all contacts and show them in tableview .In my method i fetched just one phone number of contact . my question is how to fetch all phone numbers of contact in my method .

my model and feching method :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Contacts

class ContactsModel : NSObject {
    let givenName:String
    let familyName:String
    let phoneNumber:String
    let emailAddress:String
    var identifier: String
    var image:UIImage

    init(givenName:String,familyName:String,phoneNumber:String,emailAddress:String,identifier:String,image:UIImage) {
        self.givenName = givenName
        self.familyName = familyName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.image = image
    }

    class func generateModelArray() -> [ContactsModel]{
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        var contactsData = [ContactsModel]()
        let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
        try? contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stoppingPointer) in
            let givenName = contact.givenName
            let familyName = contact.familyName
            let emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value ?? ""
            let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""
            let identifier = contact.identifier
            var image = UIImage()
            if contact.thumbnailImageData != nil{
                image = UIImage(data: contact.thumbnailImageData!)!

            }else if  contact.thumbnailImageData == nil ,givenName.isEmpty || familyName.isEmpty{
                image = UIImage(named: "usertwo")!
            }
            contactsData.append(ContactsModel(givenName: givenName, familyName: familyName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber as String, emailAddress: emailAddress as String, identifier: identifier, image: image))
        })
        return contactsData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having it as a String, use an array of strings.

```
class ContactsModel : NSObject {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let phoneNumber: [String]
    let emailAddress: String
    var identifier: String
    var image: UIImage

    init(givenName:String, familyName:String, phoneNumber:[String], emailAddress:String, identifier:String, image:UIImage) {
        self.givenName = givenName
        self.familyName = familyName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.image = image
    }

    class func generateModelArray() -> [ContactsModel]{
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        var contactsData = [ContactsModel]()
        let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
        try? contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stoppingPointer) in
            let givenName = contact.givenName
            let familyName = contact.familyName
            let emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value ?? ""
            let phoneNumber: [String] = contact.phoneNumbers.map{ $0.value.stringValue }
            let identifier = contact.identifier
            var image = UIImage()
            if contact.thumbnailImageData != nil{
                image = UIImage(data: contact.thumbnailImageData!)!

            }else if  contact.thumbnailImageData == nil ,givenName.isEmpty || familyName.isEmpty{
                image = UIImage(named: "usertwo")!
            }
            contactsData.append(ContactsModel(givenName: givenName, familyName: familyName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, emailAddress: emailAddress as String, identifier: identifier, image: image))
        })
        return contactsData
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this Use of unresolved identifier 'CNContactStore'

Comment: Did you `import Contacts`?

Comment: By the way: I didn't write/further inspect the code, I just corrected the one error in it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can access contacts from `contact framework` starting from `iOS 9`.

Contacts Framework provides contacts not only from database of you iphone or ipad device but also from various sources like iCloud account and then return the associated contacts. We can also search and filter the contacts using this Contacts Framework.

1) Make an instance of CNContactStore

```
let store = CNContactStore()
```

2) Add keys which you required in user contact info

```
let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactNicknameKey]
```

3) Execute a query to fetch all user names

```
   do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: CNContactFetchRequest.init(keysToFetch: keysToFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor]), usingBlock: { (contact, pointer) -> Void in
            print("contact = ","\(contact)")
            // Here Append this contact into your ViewModel Array.
        })
    } catch {
        print("something wrong happened")
    }
```

> Note: Don't forget to add privacy description for accessing contacts
>   information into info.plist

Comment: Do I need to import a library to use CNContactStore?